# How to set z-index for a shadow (CSS)

Tags: html, css

Say I have a box with z-index:4 + CSS shadow.
Say I have another box with z-index:2;

How do I make the shadow from the object 1 to be on top of object 2?

Comment: Then, Put the object 1 on top of object 2!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what you are looking for

HTML

```
<div id="shadow"> </div>
<div id="under"> </div>
```

CSS

```
#shadow {
    background-color: #35BFFF;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    float: left;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
}
#under {
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}
​
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vgvtu/1/)**
​

Answer (score -1):

The ordering of the shadows, i.e. which shadow falls on which div, is set by the z-index of the divs, and cannot be set independently, if that's what you're asking.

Divs with greater z-index will be on top of those with lower `z-index`, and will cast shadows on them.

My [homepage](http://www.iiserk.net/~abhra) has a couple of divs with shadows and with different `z-index`es. You can resize the browser window, make them overlap and see the effect for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

put object 1 over object 2, object 1 should not have shadow at the bottom.